# downloaded images have the same file size and are corrupted

Tags: python, web-scraping

All images downloaded from the image scraper have the same file size of 130 kb and are corrupted and cannot be seen in the image viewer.

I really have no idea what the problem is.

Anyone please give me some advice on this matter.

```
import requests
import parsel
import os
import time

url = 'https://movie-screencaps.com/movie-directory/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
selector = parsel.Selector(response.text)

movie_list = selector.xpath('//div[@class="tagindex"]/ul/li')

for li in movie_list:
    movie_name = li.xpath('.//a/text()').get().strip()
    movie_url = li.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
    print(movie_name, movie_url)

    # dir = f'download/{movie_name}'
    dir = f'{movie_name}'

    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)
    
    page_response = requests.get(movie_url, headers=headers)
    page_selector = parsel.Selector(page_response.text)

    page_text = page_selector.xpath('//div[@class="wp-pagenavi"]/text()').get()
    last_page = int(page_text.split(' ')[-1])

    for page in range(1, last_page + 1):
        page_url = f'{movie_url}/page/{page}'
        print(f'===== Downloading from page {page} =====')

        image_response = requests.get(url=page_url, headers=headers)
        image_selector = parsel.Selector(image_response.text)

        images_url_list = image_selector.xpath('//div[@align="center"]/a/@href').getall()

        for image_url in images_url_list:
            image_data = requests.get(url=page_url, headers=headers).content
            # print(image_data)
            file_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]

            with open(f'{dir}/{file_name}', mode='wb') as f:
                f.write(image_data)
                print(file_name)
                
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: have you tried printing out the image_data and checking if they are indeed the image byte data and not something else?

Comment: @rcshon I just did. I can see lots of source code.

Comment: source doe as in html code? then that it is likely the URL is either pointing to a URL that returns HTML instead of an image or they have some guards against requesting for an image directly.

Comment: @rcshon You mean all images are protected right? Hmm....This website seems like a easy, but not really is.

Comment: Oh no i just realized you have a typo: your request is fetching the `page_url` instead of `image_url`. Left an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a typo where you are fetching the `page_url` for each image_url instead of fetching the `image_url`:

```
...
for image_url in images_url_list:
    image_data = requests.get(url=page_url, headers=headers).content
    file_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]
...
```

Should be:

```
...
for image_url in images_url_list:
    # Typo is here...
    image_data = requests.get(url=image_url, headers=headers).content
    file_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]
...
```

Comment: Oh!!! My mistake. Thank you!! It works now.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and you just got a little mistake

change:

```
image_data = requests.get(url=page_url, headers=headers).content
```

to:

```
image_data = requests.get(url=image_url, headers=headers).content
```

tested and works just fine :)